# Jquery append a list to specific element by id

Tags: jquery

I have this html:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
<div id="gamelist"></div>
</div>
```

and i want to place a unordered list in the gamelist div via Jquery.

```
                var gamenr = 0;
            $.each(response.payload, function(key, value) { 
                    //alert(key + ': ' + value);
                $('#gamelist').append("<ul id='"+gamenr+"' class='game'></ul>");

                $.each(value, function(key, value){
                    //alert(key +': ' + value);     
                    $("#gamelist").attr('id', gamenr).append("<li>"+value+"</li>");
                });
                gamenr++;
            });
```

The only thing that shows up, is the first value.
gamenr is supposed to make a 'unique but not so beautifull' id.

I'd like to know why the rest of the values wont show up.

Thanks in advance,

Tim A

Comment: what do you have in response.payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing the ID of `#gamelist` on the first iteration, and then you're trying to append to `#gamelist` in second iteration etc. which is an element that no longer exists, as you changed the ID in the first iteration :

```
var gamenr = 0;
$.each(response.payload, function(key, value) {
    var gamelist = $('<ul />', {id: 'a_'+(gamenr++), 'class':'game'});

    $.each(value, function(j, k) {
        var li = $('<li />', {text: k});
        gamelist.append(li);
    });

    $('#gamelist').append(gamelist);
});​
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick awnser. :)

Answer (score 0):

You append `<li>` elements to the same `<div>` block but not to the appended `<ul>`:

```
var gamenr = 0;
$.each(response.payload, function(key, value) {
    $("#gamelist").append("<ul id='" + gamenr + "' class='game'></ul>");

    $.each(value, function(key, value) {
        $("#" + gamenr).append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
    });

    gamenr++;
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this

```
$("#gamelist").attr('id', gamenr)
```

it will set the id for the element with id `gamelist` to the content of gamenr. This is not what you wanted. Try this instead

```
$('#'+gamenr)
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the following code

```
$("#gamelist").attr('id', gamenr).append("<li>"+value+"</li>");
```

into next one

```
$("#gamelist ul[id='" + gamenr + "']").append("<li>"+value+"</li>");
```

Comment: Why not `$("#" + gamenr)`? It's faster.

Comment: it may be another elements with id = 0 or 1, etc. outside #gamelist

Comment: No, it can't be, otherwise the markup is invalid. Ids should be unique.

Comment: it' true if it just one page. but if it just a ajax module - you never can be sure about id=0 :)

Comment: If you are architect you should be sure :)

Comment: if i am architect i'll never allow id=0 =)
adeneo's anwer right because of id: 'a_'+(gamenr++)